# Can a service update a controller in Spring boot for long processes

Tags: java, spring

this is a question more about communication between **service** and **controller** annotated classes in spring boot. I have a **RestController** class that exposes a POST mapping which calls a method in the **Service** class. Now this method may take a long time running; hence there is a need to send some kind of feedback to the controller.

Is there any mechanism which allows a service to call/update a method/variable in the controller?

Comment: You'd return from the service to the controller to say it's started whatever process and run the process in  a different thread.

Comment: can we obtain the thread status from the service class when it is started in the controller?

Comment: When you say send feedback back to the controller, do you mean the controller or to the client that has POSTed?

Comment: feedback to the controller as mentioned

Comment: Why do you need to provide feedback to the controller if not to relay it to the requester?

Comment: there is a need to feedback to the controller first, which then we could perhaps use websocket to relay the feedback to the requester on the websocket channel

Comment: Surely you would just use a websocket both ways then? Also a controller shouldn't be handling logic like that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

one of the most simplest ways is passing some `lamda` function from the controller to the service and call it from the service like this

Controller Class

```
@RestController
public class controller {
    @Autowired
    Service service;

    public void foo() {
            service.foo(..parms, (message/*any params you want*/) -> {
                // here the body that will receive the message from the service
                System.out.print(message);
            });
    }
}
```

Service Class

```
public class Service {
    // updateStatus here is the function you will send the update to the controller from
    public void foo(...params, updateStatus) {
        updateStatus("starting the process...");
        // do some code
        updateStatus("in progress...");
        // do some code
        updateStatus("completed");
    }
}
```